# How to keep all values from one column if the column besides them has at least one NOT nan value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

i have a similar dataframe with two columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df=pd.DataFrame({'id_col':sorted([1,2,3]*2),'rate':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,9]})
```

what i have is

| id_col | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN |
| 1 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 5.0 |
| 3 | NaN |
| 3 | 9.0 |

and what i want is

| id_col | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 5.0 |
| 3 | NaN |
| 3 | 9.0 |

i want to keep all the id_col values that have at least 1 non NaN val

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask and use `transform` to broadcast the boolean mask to other member of the group:

```
m = df.groupby('id_col')['rate'].transform(max).notna()
out = df[m]
```

Note: you have many ways to accomplished that but many used `groupby_transform`.

Output:

```
>>> out
   id_col  rate
2       2   NaN
3       2   5.0
4       3   NaN
5       3   9.0
```

Details:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, m.rename('mask')], axis=1)
   id_col  rate   mask
0       1   NaN  False  # False because the max is null (NaN)
1       1   NaN  False
2       2   NaN   True  # True because the max is non null (5)
3       2   5.0   True
4       3   NaN   True  # True because the max is non null (9)
5       3   9.0   True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) and [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) to create a boolean mask and then subset the dataframe.

```
df[df.groupby('id_col')['rate'].transform(pd.Series.first_valid_index).notna()]
```

Output:

```
   id_col  rate
2       2   NaN
3       2   5.0
4       3   NaN
5       3   9.0
```

Comment: what happened that made you to switch the answer to the other one, just curious :) not asking you to change decision.

Comment: i was having a bit of trouble of understanding about the first_valid_index. Of course it worked as i tried it but i tried to keep it simple for me. @SomeDude

Comment: Ok, not to change your answer but what `first_valid_index` is it goes through values in a series and gets the first index where it found a non-NA value. so if series has all NA values it won't find any and returns NA. But `max` on the other hand doesn't stop at first non-NA value it will go through all values to calculate the max which is not needed in your case.